# Limit resource usage (CPU) when running PHP script in CLI mode

Tags: windows-server-2008

**Background**

I am calling using `exec()` from a PHP script to call the PHP executable `php.exe` in CLI mode to run a script.

The command I am sending looks like:

`exec('/path/to/php.exe /path/to/myscript.php');`

The issue is that the process that is lunched is using 99% - 100% of the CPU.

**Is there a way to set a priority for the process when launching the script?**

Comment: Is this causing performance issues? Are there other processes vying for CPU time? If not, there's really nothing you can do to resolve this.

Comment: Yes, it's causing temporary timeouts from the Apache server running on the same machine.

Comment: Oh, cripes...you're on windows. Well good luck with that. I haven't a clue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the answers suggest running the script in Low priority.

`start /low`.

Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: That's probably about as good as you're going to get, and it should set the process to only take CPU cycles that aren't being used by a process with a higher priority.